# Routing on Centos 7.3 to Internet

Tags: centos, virtualbox, routing

I have look for, but all I tried, doesn't work

I have two machines with Centos, **Machine 1** with a **enp0s3** (`192.168.56.99 IP`), and the **Machine 2** with (**enp0s8** `192.168.56.101` and **enp0s3** `10.0.2.15 IPs`). As you can see, my internal network is the `192.168.56.0/24`, and I want to connect the Machine 1 to internet through the Machine 2.

In case it matters, these are VMs running in VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host.

How could I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is to used netcat

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Could you give me some web page, to help me? Thanks

Comment: CentOS 5, 6 or 7?

Comment: @jsbillings Centos 7.3

Comment: 192.168.56.0/24 looks like a VirtualBox network. Are these VMs? If so, is one the Host?

Comment: @roaima yes it is a VirtualBox network. Both are guests, my host is Windows 10.

Comment: Does machine2 have confirmed Internet access already?

Comment: @roaima yes, machine 2 has internet access.

Answer (score 1):

`iptables` should be your friend for your gateway machine, e.g. configured similar to [this Debian guide for setting up a gateway](https://debian-administration.org/article/23/Setting_up_a_simple_Debian_gateway), which uses eth0 to be the internal network card and eth1 as the external address and then provides following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# run as root

#
# delete all existing rules.
#
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X

# Always accept loopback traffic
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT


# Allow established connections, and those not coming from the outside
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i ! eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing connections from the LAN side.
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT

# Masquerade.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

# Don't forward from the outside to the inside.
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth1 -j REJECT

# Enable routing.
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: When I try to do `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -i ! enp0s3-j ACCEPT` it says that enp0s3 is a bad argument

Comment: Doing in this way it doesn't show an error: `iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW ! -i enp0s3-j ACCEPT`, but I can't still do a ping to 8.8.8.8 from my machine 1. Have I to execute the script when machine 1 is up, or have I to do something on machine 1?
Thanks.